# How to display UNICODE fraction characters in verbatim?

Tags: unicode, fractions

I have the following snippet in my document, but the `⅔` is not displaying:

```
\begin{verbatim}
This is not displayed: ⅔
\end{verbatim}
```

The rendered version looks like this:

> [image]

Is there any document setting I can change to use these special characters in monospace blocks?

If not, what are the alternatives?

The error I see in the logs is:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ⅔ (U+2154)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.173 \end{verbatim}

You may provide a definition with
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter
```

---

I am using Overleaf for working on my document.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  For a glyph to appear in the output, it must be present in the used font.  Your question doesn't identify the document class or any relevant fonts that are used; without this information, it's impossible to say more.  However, there aren't very many (monospace) fonts that contain the glyphs for such fractions.  You'll have to find one that does, and explicitly load it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I just use the default monospace font for `verbatim`... How can I change it and what font would work better?

Comment: The default monospace font definitely doesn't have preformed fractions.  There's a web tool that can be searched to find the Unicode value for the glyph, but unfortunately, I don't remember its name at the moment.  That tool may identify fonts that contain the glyph, but I'm not sure of that either.  Some web searching should turn up some possibilities and then adding more details to your question should invite a useful answer.

Comment: Hi Ionică, I've removed the Overleaf tag because the problem is not specific to Overleaf: you'll see this with any TeX system if the font you select in your LaTeX code doesn't contain the glyph. (In fact, you should see a warning or error message about the missing glyph in the .log file, depending on your font setup). But as Barbara has mentioned, in order to see what's going on we need to know what fonts you're using. A great way to do this is to create a minimal working example and post the code for that full document instead of a snippet: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/21344

Comment: @PaulGessler Checking the log files helped — by using `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2154}{\(\frac{2}{3}\)}` I can display a fraction but I would like to get the diagonal fraction if possible.

Comment: `\setmonofont{Unifont}` (with xelatex) supply that glyph, but you will not like the result .... (is a bitmap font).